# REST API in laravel with facebook login

Tags: php, laravel, rest

I am building app using laravel + vue and rest api. It is possible to authenticate users with facebook in my app using rest? What I have to learn to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Laravel socialite provides the boilerplate for the oAuth.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#social-authentication